# argparse add_argument() Flags Not Being Executed

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to add an argument called 'flags' and do something with the the flag that's entered in the command line depending on what's entered, however the program isn't doing anything with the flag that's entered.

The input needs to be in the format: `program.py -flag`.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-avgtime', '-avgtemp', '-maxtime', '-maxtemp',
                        nargs='?', dest='flags')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.flags is not None:
        if args.flags == '-avgtime':
            # print something
        elif args.flags == '-avgtemp':
            # print something
        elif args.flags == '-maxtime':
            # print something
        elif args.flags == '-maxtemp':
            # pint something
    else:
        print "Command Not Executed"
```

When I enter the command `python program.py -avgtime` it just prints the "Command Not Executed" statement because the args.flags Namespace is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the `add_mutually_exclusive_group()` method. The [add_mutually_exclusive_group](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) method

> "will make sure that only one of the arguments in the mutually
>   exclusive group was present on the command line."

Also, by setting the value of each flag to be false in the  `add_argument()` method's parameters and only setting a flag to true when it is used, I am able to determine which flag was used.

```
flags = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=False)

flags.add_argument('-avgtime', action='store_true', default=False)
flags.add_argument('-avgtemp', action='store_true', default=False)
flags.add_argument('-maxtime', action='store_true', default=False)
flags.add_argument('-maxtemp', action='store_true', default=False)

flag_is_set = args.avgtime or args.avgtemp or args.maxtime or args.maxtemp

if flag_is_set:
    if args.avgtime:
        # print something
    elif args.avgtemp:
        # print something
    elif args.maxtime:
        # print something
    elif args.maxtemp:
        # pint something
else:
    print "Command Not Executed"
```

Comment: isn't `flag_is_set` useless?

Comment: @vault no, because only one of the flags can be used at a time and flag_is_set is being used just so I’m not checking all the flags multiple times.

Comment: ok but why don't you write a single `if ... elif ... elif ... elif ... else`?

Answer (score 1):

You either need to declare those arguments singularly or collect them under the same argument:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--flags', choices=['avgtime', 'avgtemp', 'maxtime', 'maxtemp'])
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.flags)
```

Put this code in `main.py` and execute it:

```
$ python2.7 main.py --flags maxtemp
maxtemp
```

See [choices](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#choices).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I am doing it like that is because I have to be able to write commands in the format: ```program.py -flag```. I am unable to use the *choices* option for that very reason.